# Not able to create doc library from custom list template using CSOM

Tags: custom-list, csom

I'm attempting to Create a Document Library from a custom list template using CSOM.  Using answers from similar question, I ran the following code but I'm receiving build error CS0200 Property or indexer 'ListTemplate.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    Web site = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(site, s => s.ListTemplates);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    //create a list
    ListCreationInformation info = new ListCreationInformation
    {
        Title = clientId,
        Description = "Client Library",
    };

    ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name = "ClientID");
    info.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
    info.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;

    site.Lists.Add(info);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This row

```
ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name = "ClientID");
```

should be

```
ListTemplate listTemplate = site.ListTemplates.First(lt => lt.Name.Equals("ClientID"));
```

You need to compare the values, not assign one to the other.